# C++ symbol visibility for explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, template-specialization, undefined-symbol

I create a shared library and use default symbol visibility "hidden", i.e., I explicitly have to modify visibility of anything that shall be exported. Moreover, I defined templates in the header files and explicitly instantiate them in the source files of the library to enforce compilation (and to hide the implementation from the library users). For this header file `foo.hpp`

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
  
template <typename Number>
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
Number add(const Number& a, const Number& b);
```

and this source file `foo.cpp`

```
#include "foo.hpp"

template <typename Number>
Number add(const Number& a, const Number& b)
{
  return a + b;
}

template double add(const double& a, const double& b);
template int add(const int& a, const int& b);
template mpq_class add(const mpq_class& a, const mpq_class& b);
```

the compilation with

```
g++ -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -c foo.cpp
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

gives the following (relevant) symbols (obtained via `nm -CD libfoo.so`):

```
__gmpq_add
__gmpq_init
double add<double>(double const&, double const&)
int add<int>(int const&, int const&)
```

However, I would have expected a symbol for the `mpq_class` implementation as well. Of course, if I now link to this library and try to call `add<mpq_class>` then I get an undefined symbol error. I can enforce exporting by adding an explicit instantiation for `mpq_class` in `foo.cpp` that is explicitly marked for export:

```
template <>
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
mpq_class add(const mpq_class& a, const mpq_class& b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Of course, this does not make much sense since I duplicate code or I have to forward to a joint implementation for each such function. For template classes, this seems to only happen for the contructors and destructors, but not for members.

I wonder why this happens. I would guess that this is somehow because mpq_class itself is a template class, but I find it strange.

Comment: Can you try and use the `template mpq_class add(...)` inside the code of the library explicitly and see if the export appears? I have had similar experience with Visual C++ long time ago, where I had to create a dummy function and use all required templates in order to make the compiler generate the instances.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. Unfortunately, this didn't help either: I added a function (itself being exported) that calls the add function.

Comment: I also verified that this is not a GMP issue: the problem persists if I replace `mpq_class` by a simple class that implements `operator+`.

Comment: I just figured that there are plenty of bug reports in GCC about symbol visibility: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102380

Answer (score 0):

This thread may be a zombie, but I was researching this problem and figured this information may help somebody else!

I started with this code:

In the header file:

```
#ifdef MY_LIB_STATIC
#    define MY_LIB_API
#elif defined(WIN32)
#    ifdef MY_LIB_EXPORTS
#        define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#        define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#else
#     ifdef MY_LIB_EXPORTS
#         define MY_LIB_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#     else
#         define MY_LIB_API
#     endif
#endif

template <class T>
class Container
{
public:

    size_type size() const;
};
```

In a C++ file:

```
template <class T>
size_t Container<T>::size() const
{
    return m_impl->size();
}

template class MY_LIB_API Container<Port*>;  // Port is a class
```

I then use call size() from a client, MySourceFile.cpp.

This works fine on Windows/Visual Studio, but when using -fvisibility=hidden on Linux/gcc, it gives an error like:

```
ld: MySourceFile.cpp:115: undefined reference to `Container<Port*>::size() const'
```

The solution is to put MY_LIB_API on every declaration, so in the header:

```
template <class T>
class MY_LIB_API Container
{
public:

    size_type size() const;
};
```

My guess:

- The default visibility is hidden.
- If there is no visibility attribute on a class, it uses the automatic setting of hidden.
- Now, there are two competing class declarations, and the one that says "default" loses, so it becomes hidden.

The use of the word "default" to mean non-hidden, rather than to mean to use the default specified on the command line, makes this all a bit obtuse unfortunately.